# How to hide SQL username and passwords from Github if using AppHarbor/Heroku to deploy?

Tags: heroku, github, web-config, connection-string, appharbor

Basically, I push code to Github and then AppHarbor/Heroku has a hook that builds from the latest commit.

If I `.gitignore` the file itself, AppHarbor/Heroku can't have the built application connect to the database because it can only see what's commited.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this bit in AppHarbor's documentation: `When you push you code, we'll replace the value "Debug" depending on the current environment: While running unit tests "Environment" is set to "Test" and when your application is deployed and is running on a server, "Environment" equals "Release".` - So does does the Key change, or the value change?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with AppHarbor, but Heroku exposes environment variables with the database connection parameters so that you don't have to put them in git.

Comment: AppHarbor also has Configuration Variables, so that sounds like a good choice!